# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure' what(): basic

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm approximately new to c++ and I have some problem when I want to read a matrix from a file.
here is my matrix in a file:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.0344828   0.323538    0.0108884   2.6302  -0.00601043     0.0019921   2.37015
0.0689655   0.315323    0.00207342  3.92065     -0.00923253     0.00402598  3.35243
0.103448    0.175781    -0.063686   4.23273     -0.00881114     0.0056472   3.79407
0.137931    0.0224418   -0.136528   4.29968     -0.00513587     0.00650649  4.04466
0.172414    -0.0932421  -0.183356   4.33218     -0.000438406    0.00697551  4.20336
0.206897    -0.148808   -0.193323   4.40354     0.00352467  0.00698478  4.31558
0.241379    -0.16686    -0.172197   4.51575     0.00628366  0.00647283  4.40149
0.275862    -0.164914   -0.129917   4.63925     0.00770706  0.00567122  4.46758
0.310345    -0.128657   -0.092887   4.73243     0.00787571  0.00482414  4.52067
0.344828    -0.0776035  -0.0664981  4.79118     0.00743055  0.00400328  4.56789
0.37931     -0.0385587  -0.05244    4.80834     0.0061065   0.00328682  4.60748
0.413793    -0.0040996  -0.0490464  4.79264     0.00462926  0.00260406  4.64237
0.448276    0.0220397   -0.0481575  4.76923     0.00303705  0.00194038  4.67413
0.482759    0.0398955   -0.0473876  4.7406  0.00182074  0.00128583  4.70189
0.517241    0.0541651   -0.0449     4.71528     0.000727833     0.000633435     4.72829
0.551724    0.0588831   -0.0362422  4.70938     8.49119e-05     -6.27609e-05    4.75152
0.586207    0.061897    -0.0272721  4.70866     -0.000363273    -0.000773489    4.77342
0.62069     0.0606852   -0.0129192  4.7187  -0.000587166    -0.00143652     4.79323
0.655172    0.0605354   -0.000346813    4.72946     -0.000544833    -0.00204383     4.81059
0.689655    0.0587716   0.0135411   4.73842     -0.0004949  -0.00264921     4.82794
0.724138    0.0639723   0.0221793   4.74228     -0.000198867    -0.0029033  4.84047
0.758621    0.0692056   0.0307559   4.746   9.95025e-05     -0.00315412     4.85295
0.793103    0.074144    0.037433    4.74651     0.000357403     -0.00325805     4.86406
0.827586    0.0841098   0.0399013   4.75459     0.000502533     -0.00296743     4.87154
0.862069    0.0937132   0.0425136   4.76246     0.000647458     -0.00267717     4.87901
0.896552    0.0997181   0.0454041   4.77419     0.000719785     -0.00227675     4.88509
0.931034    0.104461    0.0459297   4.79986     0.000615777     -0.00159462     4.88769
0.965517    0.109204    0.0464553   4.82552     0.000511769     -0.000912495    4.89028
1   0.112065    0.0491291   4.85342     0.00040813  -0.000228803    4.89288
```

and here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

string fn, path_str;
string root("/home/mostafa/OpenFOAM/mostafa-2.1.0/run/tutorials/incompressible/pisoFoam/channelLES/Balaras/09/postProcessing/mydata/");
string endfile("/Data0_U_UMean.xy");
float fileName, h[30][95], u[30][95], v[30][95], w[30][95], data[7][30], uMean[7], vMean[30], wMean[30];
float uPrime[30][95], vPrime[30][95], wPrime[30][95];
float uPrime2Mean[30], vPrime2Mean[30], wPrime2Mean[30];
float uPrimeMean[30], vPrimeMean[30], wPrimeMean[30];
float u2_rms[30], v2_rms[30], w2_rms[30];



int main ()
{
    for (int t=0;t<96;t++)
    {
        fileName=769.999+t*10;
        string fn = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << fileName) )->str();
        path_str=root+ fn+endfile;
        const char* path=path_str.c_str();
        //myfile.open (path,ios::out);
        float data[7][30];

        ifstream myfile(path, fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
        //ifstream myfile(path);

        if (!myfile)
        {
            cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
            return 0;
        }

        //Reading the data file
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
            {
                myfile >> data[x][y];
                cout << data[x][y] << " ";
            }
            cout << "END OF ROW" <<endl;
        }

        myfile.close();

        //constructing h,u,v,w matrices
        for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            h[i][t]=data[i][0];
            u[i][t]=data[i][1];
            v[i][t]=data[i][2];
            w[i][t]=data[i][3];
            cout << w[i][t] << " ";
        }
        cout << "w[][]" << endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        for (int t=0; t<96; t++)
        {
            uMean[i]+=(u[i][t])/95;
            vMean[i]+=(v[i][t])/95;
            wMean[i]+=(w[i][t])/95;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        for (int t=0; t<96; t++)
        {
            uPrime[i][t]=u[i][t]-uMean[i];
            vPrime[i][t]=v[i][t]-vMean[i];
            wPrime[i][t]=w[i][t]-wMean[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        for (int t=0; t<96; t++)
        {
            uPrimeMean[i]+=(uPrime[i][t])/95;
            vPrimeMean[i]+=(vPrime[i][t])/95;
            wPrimeMean[i]+=(wPrime[i][t])/95;

            uPrime2Mean[i]+=pow(uPrime[i][t],2)/95;
            vPrime2Mean[i]+=pow(vPrime[i][t],2)/95;
            wPrime2Mean[i]+=pow(wPrime[i][t],2)/95;
/*
            uPrime2Mean_rms[i]+=pow(uPrime[i][t],2)/95/uMean[i];
            vPrime2Mean_rms[i]+=pow(vPrime[i][t],2)/95/vMean[i];
            wPrime2Mean_rms[i]+=pow(wPrime[i][t],2)/95/wMean[i];
            */
            u2_rms[i]=uPrime2Mean[i]/pow(uMean[i],2);
            v2_rms[i]=vPrime2Mean[i]/pow(vMean[i],2);
            w2_rms[i]=wPrime2Mean[i]/pow(wMean[i],2);
        }
    }
    /*
    ofstream Uf("home/mostafa/OpenFOAM/mostafa-2.1.0/run/tutorials/incompressible/pisoFoam/channelLES/Balaras/09/postProcessing/surfaceSampling2/Uf.xy");
    for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        myfile << h[i][1] <<"/t"<<
    }*/

    return 0;
}
```

and when I run it, it reads the file until line 12 and then it gives me this error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure'   what(): basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file

I check the code with another file which has the same matrix dimensions but different numbers and it worked correctly!

anybody knows what is the problem? and where is it?

Regards,
Mostafa

---

thanks for the reply

I think the poop is somewhere in:

```
//Reading the data file
for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 7; y++)
    {
        myfile >> data[x][y];
        cout << data[x][y] << " ";
    }
    cout << "END OF ROW" <<endl;
}
```

and you are right about the bounds.
I still have this problem

and when I'm using

```
string fn = std::to_string(fileName);
```

it says that "'to_string' is not a member of 'std'"

Comment: Why, why do you do `static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << fileName) )->str()` ?!

Comment: that's quite a code-dump. Can you reduce it?

Comment: @quantdev: that's amazing!  I wonder if the OP is a fuzzing tool.

Answer (score 5):

Your program has **undefined behavior**.

You access most of your arrays out of bounds, e.g. `h[30][95], u[30][95], v[30][95], w[30][95]` are accessed at `[29][95]` because of all those loops:

```
for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    for (int t=0; t<96; t++) 
                  ^^^^^
             // Should be 95
```

Also replace this :

```
string fn = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << fileName) )->str();
```

By :

```
string fn = std::to_string(fileName);
```